# Time complexity for N insert operations in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

If we have a sorted array containing N elements and we wish to perform N insert operations then what should be the worst case time complexity of the best approach?

I think it should be O(N log(2N)) because we can insert N elements directly at the end of the sorted array. After all the insertions, we will have 2N elements and we can perform a stable sorting algorithm on the whole 2N array which would take O(2N log(2N)) ~ O(N log(2N))

So, in total = N insertions + sorting = O(N + 2N log(2N)) = O(N log(2N))

But everywhere I see related concept it is given as O(N^2) as they are keeping the array sorted after Each insertion by making space for each insertion in between the sorted array!

Is my approach wrong? Do we have to keep the sorted array sorted after each insertion? If yes, then does this "keep the data structure same after each operation rather than making it intact after a whole series of the same operation" Rule valid for all data structures?!

Comment: *Do we have to keep the sorted array sorted after each insertion?* I don't know. What do the requirements say? And, no, not all ordered data structures have the same rule. A balanced binary search tree, for example, allows you to do an insertion in O(log n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you need.

If you need to do some operations after each insert, then `O(n^2)` is standard (finding the right spot `O(lgn)` and shifting elements `O(n)`).

If you don't need to do anything in between insertions, insert all elements at the end and sort in `O(nlgn)` so that the entire operation takes `O(nlgn)` (assuming insertion at the end takes `O(1)` time).

BTW, it will be `O(nlg(n))` because `O(nlg(2n)) = O(nlgn + nlg(2)) = O(nlgn + n) = O(nlgn)`

Comment: "If you need to do some operations after each insert, then O(n^2) is standard (finding the right spot O(lgn) and shifting elements O(n))."

That doesn't sound right. Shouldn't that be O(n * logn) rather than O(n^2) if you're one O(logn) operation followed by a O(n) operation?